# Configure Intellij IDEA to run batch file

Tags: batch-file, intellij-idea, build-automation

I'm using InteliJ IDEA (Community addition) and I found myself doing some file transfers to and from the project folder.
After reapeating the task for a while I've created some batch scripts that transfering the files automaticly. Now, I'll be much more happy if I could run the scripts directly from the IDE - by pressing a button for example...

Question is: Can I add buttons to IntelliJ IDE - that will run a batch file? If it's possible I'll be happy to know how it can be done.

Thanks!

Comment: You can add buttons linked to your external tool. Create a new question that can be answered without changing the current.

Comment: @maba - I added question - it's in http://stackoverflow.com/q/25993042/1726419

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use "External Tools" to invoke any program

Goto `Settings->External Tools` and create a tool which will open the following dialog choose the batch file for `Program`.

[image: Create Tool Dialog]

Then the tool will be available in the menu `Tools`

[image: Tools Menu]

Ref:[External Tools](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/external-tools.html)

*Update:*

If you want to link an 'External Tool' to a 'Button' in the toolbar check [How to add buttons linked to your external tool in InteliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993042)

Answer (score 22):

Also if you install "Batch Scripts Support" plugin, you will get nice file context menu actions for running batch files directly from the project view.

NOTE 2019: The original authors abandoned the plugin, but there is a maintained fork for current versions of IntelliJ: https://github.com/SimonIT/idea-batch

NOTE 2020: Even newer fork is: https://github.com/aefimov/idea-batch

[image: Context menu]

Comment: Your link gives 404, I think this is the new github repo https://github.com/aefimov/idea-batch

Answer (score 9):

Another alternative to IntelliJ 2019 is:

> Edit Configuration > Click '+' > Select Shell Script > 'In Script path:' set the .bat file location > OK > Click play button or Run once you have saved it

See image below:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Install ["Batch Scripts Support" plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/265-batch-scripts-support). Then choose **+** `->` **Batch**:

[image]