# How to add buttons linked to your external tool in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, build-automation, external-tools

I created some batch work and integrated it as ExternalTool to the IntelliJ IDEA. as described here: [Configure Intellij IDEA to run batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25968099/1726419)

But how can I add buttons to my toolbar that will activate the batch that defined as external tool?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It is quite easy.

Assuming that you already have an External Tool configured just right click on the menu bar and choose `Customize Menus and Toolbars...`:
[image]

Next step is to mark the last item (whatever that is in your setup) in `Main Toolbar` and select `Add After...`:

[image]

Now you can select your external tool from the `Choose Actions To Add` window (here you can also select an icon to use):

[image]

Action has been added:

[image]

And your button has been added to the toolbar:

[image]

Comment: In newer versions of IntelliJ IDEA, you either need to enable the Toolbar first (View > Toolbar) or open the "Menus and Toolbars" window via the preferences (Ctrl + Alt + S, Appearance & Behavior > Menus and Toolbars).