# How can I execute a one liner (without Terminal) in IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

I'd like to execute a short series of commands in IDEA. realistically the actual commands don't matter, but here it is

```
git add --all . && git stash && ( git svn dcommit || git svn rebase && git svn dcommit ) && git stash pop
```

is it possible to make this an "external tool"? without writing an actual `.sh` script? or perhaps is there some other way? I don't want to keep running it in the terminal, I'd rather click a button (or shortcut it) or find some way to make it execute after commit.

Comment: You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25968099/configure-intellij-idea-to-run-batch-file) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25993042/how-to-add-buttons-linked-to-your-external-tool-in-intelij-idea). The first link can be used to specify any kind of command, not just for batch files as mentioned.

Comment: You're probably better writing the shell script and committing it to your repository for other developers to use too.