# Define a project specific external tools in intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, build-automation, external-tools

I'm working on more than one project. I needed to define `External-Tool` to do some batch processing in one of the project. and did this as descibed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25970200/1726419

After I opened a different project I saw that the External tool of the first project is still defined in the IDE.

how can I defind a project related external tools set?

Comment: Well Run/Debug configurations are per-project. As are maven goals. Can you configure it that way, for example a maven `exec` or `antrun` plugin goal that invokes your external tool?

Comment: @vikingsteve it is possible, can I define the maven/gradle that runs te exec as a seperate button on the toolbar?

Comment: Not as a separate button, but as a separate run configuration. Click on your maven target and select "Create {target}". This will add a run configuration into your run configuration combobox on the toolbar.

Comment: In the `External Tool` setup window you can define macros that can take project specific parameters. That may help you a bit. You can even add a macro that makes the external tool prompt you for input.

Comment: Yeah this would be useful especially if your external tool uses the same keyboard shortcut across projects