# Run a bat from pyCharm

Tags: python, path, pycharm, plantuml

I have in my repository some files writen in plantUML (these are actually `.txt` files).
I also have a `.bat` which has the code line :

`java -jar plantuml.jar ../SequencesDiagrams/plantUML_file_name`.

My repository is located in the path `F:\RPS`.
I would like to know :

1. is there a way to run the `.bat` from inside pyCharm because for the moment I have to pen the bat from the file explorer.
2. is there a way remotely specify which plantUML file I want to convert to a png ? for the moment I have to manually modify the file name in the path in the `.bat`

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely" in point 2? What's your aim in point 1, do you mean just executing the `.bat` from inside PyCharm or interconnecting it with Python? Can you include a [*"Minimal, Reproducible, Example."*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the `.bat` preferably just a one line accepting arguments?

Comment: Point 1 was about executing the ```.bat```from withing pyCharm.

Point 2 was about having a script I can launch with a cmd for instance, specifying the file name, that will execute the ```.bat```. 

The code line in my post is actually the only line in the ```.bat```file. It converts the plantUML file (plantUML_file_name) into a png. The ```plantuml.jar``` is the program given by plantUML that allows such conversion.

Comment: For point 1 see [Configure Intellij IDEA to run batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25968099/2800058).